# Python Regex for Phone Numbers is acting strangely

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've developed a Python Regex that pulls phone numbers from text around 90% of the time. However, there are sometimes weird anomalies. My code is as follows:

```
phone_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4}|\d{3}[-\.\s]\d{4})')
df['phone'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: phone_pattern.findall(x))
df['phone']=df['phone'].apply(lambda y: '' if len(y)==0 else y)
df['phone'] = df['phone'].apply(', '.join)
```

This code extracts the phone numbers and appends a new column called "phone." If there are multiple numbers, they are separated by a comma.

The following text, however, generates a weird output:

```
university of blah school of blah blah blah (jane doe doe) 1234567890 1234 miller Dr E233 MILLER DR blah blah fl zipcode in the morning or maybe Monday.
```

The output my current code gives me is:

```
890 1234
```

Rather than the desired actual number of:

```
1234567890
```

This happens on a few examples. I've tried editing the regex, but it only makes it worse. Any help would be appreciated. Also, I think this question is useful, because a lot of the phone regex offered on Stackoverflow haven't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(\b\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4}|\b\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lex3oj/3)

Note that `\b` word boundary is added before the first and third only alternatives, the second one starts with `\(` pattern that matches a `(` and needs no word boundary check. There is a word boundary at the end, too. Besides, the `[-.\s]` delimiter in the first alternative is made optional, a `?` quantifier makes it match 1 or 0 times.

In Pandas, just use

```
rx = r'(\b\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{3}[-.\s]?\d{4}|\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4}|\b\d{3}[-.\s]\d{4})\b'
df['phone'] = df['text'].str.findall(rx).apply(', '.join)
```